# How to pass a variable to XQuery using XQilla in C++

Tags: c++, xml, xquery, qt6, xqilla

I am using XQilla to evaluate XQuery in C++.

In the XQuery, we define two variables: `$metadataContent` and `$nuiContent`.

Each variable maps to an XML document.

How can I pass the variable to XQuery from my C++ code, and then evaluate the query?

Comment: Are the variables declared as e.g. `declare variable $nuiContent external;` in the XQuery prolog? The dynamic context seems to have a method to set a global variable: https://fossies.org/dox/XQilla-2.3.4/classDynamicContext.html#a7a91d9bafa736b1d2de3ced42c999c42

Comment: And you can construct a `Result` from a `Sequence` and build a `Sequence` from an XML file with e.g. `Sequence seq = context->resolveDocument(X("file.xml"));`, see https://fossies.org/dox/XQilla-2.3.4/simple-context-item_8cpp_source.html.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It is declared like this:
declare variable $metadata := doc($metadataContent)
So the metadata content is the content of another xml file. So I need to pass the xml content to this xquery.

Comment: Yes, I found this example, so first I create a query:
query(xqilla.parse(X(queryContent)))
Then I get an exception says: XQException: A variable called {}metadataContent does not exist.
So I think I need to pass the xml content to the two defined variables in xquery.

Comment: Or maybe instead of pass the xml content to xquery, I can remove the two variables in the query, and just say xml file name like: devtoolsmetadata/component/@name/string() to verify the xml content? Then I should rewrite the xquery?

Comment: With `doc($metadataContent)` the value of `metadataContent` should be a URI. If you want to parse a string with XML then use `parse-xml($metadataContent)`. But that is a function introduced in XQuery 3, I think, I am not sure your implementation/your XQuery processor supports that.

Comment: Ok, but how can I pass this uri to the query?

Comment: In my understanding the key in XQuery is having `external` declaration e.g. `declare variable $nuiContent external;`, then try along the lines of https://fossies.org/dox/XQilla-2.3.4/classDynamicContext.html#a7a91d9bafa736b1d2de3ced42c999c42 e.g. `context->setExternalVariable(X("metadataContent"), context->getItemFactory()->createUntypedAtomic(X("foo.xml"), context.get()));`. I hope it takes a relative URI like `foo.xml`, if not try e.g. `file:/dir/subdir/foo.xml`.

Comment: Ok, I see, I will try. Maybe I need to restructure the xquery a bit. We were using qtxml pattern module to process the xquery, but now we upgrade qt to qt6 and the module is removed, so I need to use another library to parse the xquery. So maybe the xquery was written in the way for qtxml module to process

Comment: Note that with SaxonC there is another, maintained product on the market, that supports the latest XQuery/XPath 3.1: https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml, https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation12/index.html, https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxonmirrorhe/repository/he/revisions/he_mirror_saxon_12_4_1/entry/src/main/c/samples/cppTests/testXQuery.cpp#L265

Comment: I tried the above setExternal function seems the second parameter should be Result type but it is AnyAtomicType::Ptr now. So I get a no matching function call error

Comment: I think you can construct a `Result` from an `Item::Ptr` and that way as well from an `AnyAtomicType::Ptr`, see the constructors for `Result`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I made it work! I will try SaxonC now, since it support latest XQuery.

Comment: question about saxonc, how to set external variable for xquery? Is it setProperty function?

Comment: I had already linked to a sample showing that with https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxonmirrorhe/repository/he/revisions/he_mirror_saxon_12_4_1/entry/src/main/c/samples/cppTests/testXQuery.cpp#L265 e.g. `XQueryProcessor *queryProc3 = processor->newXQueryProcessor();` and `queryProc3->setQueryContent( "declare variable $p as xs:integer external; /*/bar + $p");` and `XdmAtomicValue *value2 = processor->makeIntegerValue(6);` and `queryProc3->setParameter("p", (XdmValue *)value2);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed from the help of @Martin Honnen
Example code here: https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxonmirrorhe/repository/he/revisions/he_mirror_saxon_12_4_1/entry/src/main/c/samples/cppTests/testXQuery.cpp#L265

Comment: Please include all the relevant information in the answer, instead of just referencing the comments.